# Retrieving a node original string

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm a newbie with xml/libxml.
What I'm trying to do is simple.

I have a node like :

```
<tag attr="example" attr2="example2"/>
```

which is stored in a xmlNode. I want to get the following xmlChar* :

```
"<tag attr="example" attr2="example2"/>"
```

I tried xmlNodeGetContent and xmlNodeListGetString but none of them seem to do what I want.

I'm using libxml2 in C. The file xml version is 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlNodeGetContent` isn't what you're looking for : check [this page](http://student.santarosa.edu/~dturover/?node=libxml2) for info on its behavior.

I think the function you're looking for is [`xmlNodeDump`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump), which will of course require a valid buffer.